# Checking whether you can open an external app & opening it with React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deep-linking

I have a third party app that apparently has some deep linking protocol (`x-mythirdpartyapp://`). I don't need to do any deep linking to the contents of it just open it. It also does not react to the corresponding url (i.e. https://mythirdpartyapp.com) so the answers for similar questions related to whatsapp are useless here.

Based on my research so far, these custom deep linking protocols are iOS only, so this should work for iOS

```
Linking.canOpenUrl("mythirdpartyapp://")

and

Linking.openUrl("mythirdpartyapp://")
```

But can't confirm them as I don't have any iOS devices.

As for Android you can apparently open intents with `Linking.sendIntent` but this is not enough as in my use case I need to know whether I can send the intent before actually sending it.

Answer (score 0):

Those do in fact work with iOS and this did the trick for Android: https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent

Here's the full solution:

```
async function canOpenApp() {
  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    return SendIntentAndroid.isAppInstalled(ANDROID_ID)
  } else {
    return Linking.canOpenURL(URL_PROTOCOL)
  }
}
async function openApp() {
  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    return SendIntentAndroid.openApp(ANDROID_ID, {})
  } else {
    return Linking.openURL(URL_PROTOCOL)
  }
}
async function openStore() {
  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    return Linking.openURL(
      `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=${ANDROID_ID}`
    )
  } else {
    return Linking.openURL(
      `https://apps.apple.com/${APP_STORE_LOCALE}/app/${APP_STORE_NAME}/id${APP_STORE_ID}`
    )
  }
}
```